# How does one manually rotate log without logrotate on open/live file?

Tags: logging, syslog, logrotate

My Google-Fu is getting me so close but just not quite there, and I guess I'm too green in Linux to put the pieces together.

I have a very large >200GB log file, still being written to. Logrotate wont get to it in time before disk space could be a concern. Also, I don't want to fire off another round of `logrotate`, because I don't want it to effect all the other targets in its config. I have added the new stanza in my `logrotate.conf` file as such:

```
/log/myDevice/myDevice.log {
  compress
  daily
  rotate 360
  maxage 360
  missingok
  compresscmd /usr/bin/xz
  dateext
  compressext .xz
  copytruncate
  olddir /log/archive/myDevice
}
```

I would like to do these things manually:

1. copytruncate : to grab off the current log file, but allow syslog-ng to keep chugging along on the current open/live file
2. *(not above in the logrotate.conf)* `split` : to break up the current log roll into smaller chunks
3. `xz` : compress over to archive folder

I can `split(1)` and `xz(1)` just fine, but when I try to grab off the target file, no dice.

I tried `sudo mv myDevice.log ZmyDevice.log && touch myDevice.log`, but syslog-ng just moves with the original file (and its new name) and keeps writes merrily away. *Which made a bit of since when I thought about how the file is being referenced by syslog-ng.*

So I'm trying to figure out how to do some sort of a manual `copytruncate` in order to cut the file to another one "in place" as it were, and let syslog-ng keep chugging away at what it wants.

Comment: Do you need the contents of the existing file?

Comment: Yes. I want to split up and archive the current contents inside of my `myDevice.log` file. I thought about making a temporary logrotate.conf file with just this one stanza in it, and running it against the file, but I don't want the compressed file to be that of the original >200GB size. My thoughts were to use `split` to break it up first, then just `xz` them myself into the archive folder. This way the current (or what would be left as syslog-ng would still be writing to it) would get logrotate'ed tomorrow on schedule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the file, then send a SIGHUP to the syslog-ng process:

kill -HUP

which will cause it to re-open all it's open files, thus releasing the file you just moved/renamed and allowing you to carry on.  It'll then open /log/myDevice/myDevice.log fresh and start writing to that.

Comment: I read the `kill -HUP` answer in another SF post, could a more verbose explanation of how this works under the covers be provided? It sounds right, but I'd like to learn more about the mechanisms that drive the action. What I know about it is "Many daemons will reload their configuration files and reopen their logfiles instead of exiting when receiving this signal". But is syslog-ng known for coming back normally, or just exiting and staying exited?

Comment: I don't know in detail how syslog-ng implements SIGHUP processing under the covers, just that it claims to reopen files when it receives it: http://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-3.3-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-v3.3-guide-admin-en/html/configuring_destinations_file.html, specifically "Also, after rotating the log files, reload syslog-ng OSE using the syslog-ng-ctl reload command, or use another method to send a SIGHUP to syslog-ng OSE."

Comment: This definitely did the trick! Though for anyone else in my awkward spot, the command I did was:  
  `mv myDevice.log ZmyDevice.log && kill -HUP \`cat /var/run/syslogd.pid\``

Comment: how to do this in windows

Answer (score 0):

Find which processes have the file open: `fuser /path/to/file`. Then use `kill -SIGSTOP` to suspend the process(es) that is writing to the file. Then rotate the file, copy it, truncate it, whatever you need to do, then resume the process(es) with `kill -SIGCONT`.